# How to set up Github CI for Rails + Rspec + Capybara & Selenium Webdrivers for a multi domain app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, github-actions

## The problem

When running on Github's CI, I get a `SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known` when trying to visit a page.

```
     2.1) Failure/Error: visit '/'

          SocketError:
            getaddrinfo: Name or service not known



          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:110:in `initialize'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:110:in `new'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:110:in `find_available_port'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:37:in `initialize'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:93:in `new'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:93:in `initialize'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara.rb:424:in `new'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara.rb:424:in `block in session_pool'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara.rb:315:in `current_session'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/system/register_system_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'


     2.2) Failure/Error: server = TCPServer.new(host, 0)

          SocketError:
            getaddrinfo: Name or service not known



          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:110:in `initialize'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:110:in `new'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:110:in `find_available_port'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:37:in `initialize'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:93:in `new'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:93:in `initialize'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara.rb:424:in `new'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara.rb:424:in `block in session_pool'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara.rb:315:in `current_session'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:54:in `save_image'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:25:in `take_screenshot'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:37:in `take_failed_screenshot'
          # /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/setup_and_teardown.rb:21:in `after_teardown'
```

Tests run correctly on my local environment with `rspec` and both `selenium_google_chrome_headless` or `selenium_google_chrome`.

## The app

- It's a multi domain app so my tests run with

```rb
before { Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.myapp.test" }
```

- Library versions

  - Ruby 2.5.5
  - `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4'`
  - `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'`
  - `capybara (3.33.0)`
  - `webdrivers (4.4.1)`

    - `selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)`
- Here is my Github CI workflow

```yaml
env:
  RUBY_VERSION: 2.5.5
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Start database
        run: |
          sudo systemctl start mysql
      - name: Set up Ruby 2.5.5
        run: |
          sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get -y install rvm
          source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
          rvm install ${{ env.RUBY_VERSION }}
      - name: setup-chromedriver
        uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@v1.0.1
      - name: Build and test
        env:
          DATABASE_PASSWORD: root
        run: |
          source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
          rvm use ${{ env.RUBY_VERSION }}
          gem install bundler
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
          mysql -uroot -p${{ env.DATABASE_PASSWORD }} --execute="CREATE DATABASE myapp_test"
          RAILS_ENV=test rails db:setup
          bundle exec rspec spec/system
```

Answer (score 1):

Using :headless_chrome as javascript browser with [this](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/issues/126#issuecomment-500263938) configurations in spec/spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```rb
Capybara.server = :puma
```

to my `spec/rails_helper.rb` file seems to fix my main issue.

My tests are still not passing on Github Actions but it looks to be a different issue.